# How to retrieve Dynamics 365 Security/Team members in Power Automate Approval?

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

I'm new to Microsoft CRM and Power Automate. I'm trying to implement the Quote approval process.

As per the requirement, I have to create a team in Dynamic 365 > Security > Team (as below)

[image]

Then I created a 'Start and wait for an approval' action and tried to select the 'Quote Approvers' team which I created in the above screen. But can't select it.

[image]

Is there a way to get the team members into that action? or workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Assigned to” can accept user, comma separated email address or AD group. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/group-approvals?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#send-an-approval-to-a-microsoft-365-group)

If we have to pass a set of users from CRM owner team, then we have to build the custom logic.

1. Query the team members - [Reference](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Get-Team-Members-of-TEAM-Typ-Owner-in-CRM-dynamics-365-using/td-p/1372823)
2. Set the variable and use - [Reference](https://www.intelogy.co.uk/blog/assigning-microsoft-flow-approvals-to-sharepoint-groups/)